# nvidia-352 driver not working with kernel 4.2.0-29

Tags: nvidia, kernel

after the latest kernel update for wily, to 4.2.0-29, i can no longer load the nvidia-352 driver. After noticing it was not being loaded on boot, i used `modprobe nvidia` to try loading it manually, and got an error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia_352': Invalid argument

I found the following in my kern.log file:

```
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.113976] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_init
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114001] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_init (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114133] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114136] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_handle_to_fd (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114178] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_private_object_init
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114180] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_private_object_init (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114424] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_handle_create
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114426] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_handle_create (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114534] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_set_busid
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114536] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_set_busid (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114609] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_pci_exit
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114611] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_pci_exit (err -22)
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114667] nvidia: disagrees about version of symbol drm_gem_prime_export
Feb 21 19:34:44 inanna kernel: [78265.114669] nvidia: Unknown symbol drm_gem_prime_export (err -22)
```

I have also booted into kernel 4.2.0-28 and the driver was initially not found (i had been running 4.2.0-27 previously, installed -28, but not bothered to reboot until after the -29 update). I used `apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-352` and then the driver loaded with no problem. I tried the same after booting back into the -29 kernel, but still no luck.

Is there anything else i can try? I've seen mention of newer (but still beta) versions of the nvidia driver -- is it worth trying one?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel 4.2.0-29 is not released yet.

It is a testing kernel in the `proposed` repository. It may have issues.

The only reason to turn on the `proposed` repository is to find this kind of issues and report them to Launchpad.

You can do it by running `ubuntu-bug linux` command.

If you do not intend to test software, but to use a stable system, boot from the previous stable `4.2.0-27` kernel, remove all newer kernels and disable the `proposed` repository.

After you remove the repository run for Ubuntu 15.10

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

for Ubuntu 14.04.4 run

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-wily
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, as of writing this : the latest stable and tested kernel available is `4.2.0-27-generic`.
Boot with this kernel and everything should work flawlessly ... **if not** reinstall the NVIDIA drivers.

Uninstall the NVIDIA drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
sudo reboot
```

Generally it is recommended to use the NVIDIA drivers from the official Ubuntu repositories.
When there are problems with these drivers, you can install the latest official NVIDIA drivers.

Uninstall the NVIDIA drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo reboot
```

Reinstall the NVIDIA drivers - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

My personal experience :

I installed these drivers shortly after the release and they are working great without any issue.
NVIDIA drivers 361.28 are the latest official drivers version from the NVIDIA long-lived branch.

Updated information :

A new kernel `4.2.0-30-generic` is available in the repositories.

Ubuntu 15.10 Linux kernel -> [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2908-1](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2908-1/)

Ubuntu 14.04 Linux kernel -> [Ubuntu Security Notice USN-2908-2](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/usn-2908-2/)

Comment: I do not think there is any need to re-install Nvidia drivers.

Comment: Ok, got rid of the proposed repository, updated, and also noticed there was a new 4.2.0-30 kernel. This kernel has the exact same problem, though. I also tried the nvidia-361 driver instead, following the above instructions: same results. So something broke between the -28 and -29 kernels, and remains broken in the newly released -30 kernel.